# Video Uploading in Android

Tags: android

I wants to upload video file to server even after app is force stopped/closed. Right now video uploading process  stops as soon as i force stop the app. Uploading is fine when app is in foreground and in background but when we stop the app by long pressing home button or by going through setting/app manager .

I have already used service and thread but it did not work.

Comment: had you tried asynctask ?

Comment: Thanks Biraj,yes, we try but asynctask also stopped as soon as we stop app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void uploadData(String filePath) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>() {
                        protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
                            //paste your uploading code here. this will work
                        }
                    }.execute(Params);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```